# jointjs rect text overflow

Tags: javascript, html, jointjs

I'm using jointjs to draw diagrams.
My problem is that in my jointjs rect, the text inside is too long. The size of my rect is assumed fixed.
I have used joint.util.breakText to control the height and width, but the overflow disappears. And I have set the font-size small enough. How to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your overflow disappear. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case I have empty shapes. By click-event I can add a comment (text) to the shape. This example enlarges the shape's size and wraps the text inside additionally. Hope it helps!

```
     function enterText(viewShape) {
         var shapeText = prompt('Enter your new comment:', '');
         if (viewShape.model.id === 'CommentID') {

             //change comment text here
             if (shapeText.length > 5) {

                 var wraptext = joint.util.breakText(shapeText, {
                     width: 200
                     //height: optionalHeight
                 });
                 //resize attribute and add it to paper
                 viewShape.model.resize(wraptext.length * 8, 67);
                 viewShape.model.attr('text/text', wraptext).attr('text/ref-y', 0.45);

             } else {
                 viewShape.model.attr('text/text', shapeText).attr('text/ref-y', 0.45);

             }
         }
     }
```